# Discretize all rasters in stack in R

Tags: r, spatial, raster, discretization

I am trying to simultaneously discretize 5 stacked rasters in R into quartile values. I've written the following loop to do so, but it doesn't seem to be working correctly. In the code, "stack.disc" is the stack and "quartiles" is a 5 column data frame with the 5 rasters as columns and their quartile values listed in the rows.

```
for(i in 1:ncol(quartiles)) {
  for(j in 1:length(stack.disc@layers[[i]])) {
    if(isTRUE(stack.disc@layers[[i]]@data@values[j] >= quartiles[1,i] &
                stack.disc@layers[[i]]@data@values[j] < quartiles[2,i])) {
        stack.disc@layers[[i]]@data@values[j] = 1 
    }
    if(isTRUE(stack.disc@layers[[i]]@data@values[j] >= quartiles[2,i] &
                stack.disc@layers[[i]]@data@values[j] < quartiles[3,i])) {
        stack.disc@layers[[i]]@data@values[j] = 2
    }
    if(isTRUE(stack.disc@layers[[i]]@data@values[j] >= quartiles[3,i] &
                stack.disc@layers[[i]]@data@values[j] < quartiles[4,i])) {
        stack.disc@layers[[i]]@data@values[j] = 3
    }
    if(isTRUE(stack.disc@layers[[i]]@data@values[j] >= quartiles[4,i] &
                stack.disc@layers[[i]]@data@values[j] <= quartiles[5,i])) {
        stack.disc@layers[[i]]@data@values[j] = 4
    }
  }
}
```

The code runs but only on the first 3 rasters in the stack. Any ideas why it isn't working for the last 2?

Thank you!

Comment: Maybe you should use one statement with many `else if ...` instead of five separate `if ...` statements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `cut` to reclassify rasters (it has a raster* method).

```
s2 = stack(lapply(names(stack.disc), function(n) 
                  cut(stack.disc[[n]], breaks=quartiles[,n])))
```

Or, slightly shorter version using `stackApply`

```
stackApply(stack.disc, 1:5, function(r, na.rm) cut(r, breaks=quartiles[,names(r)]))
```

**Some reproducible data to demonstrate:**

```
stack.disc = stack(lapply(1:5, function(i) raster(matrix(rnorm(25, i),5,5))))
quartiles = t(quantile(stack.disc))
#         layer.1  layer.2  layer.3  layer.4  layer.5
# 0%   -1.0937068 0.498138 1.142862 2.229032 3.078026
# 25%   0.5171343 1.799564 2.496730 3.108751 4.484395
# 50%   1.1293477 2.099162 2.896269 3.818627 4.939167
# 75%   1.6348539 2.481976 3.615938 4.693733 5.314098
# 100%  2.4405652 3.511051 4.886970 5.456095 6.929452
```

Comment: Much simpler and cleaner, thank you!. I found an error earlier in my code preventing two of the rasters from being processed properly (for both my code and yours), but it worked after catching that. Much appreciated.

Comment: You're welcome.  For future reference, if you ever find yourself trying to access raster slots directly (the `@` operator) its a red flag that there's almost certainly a simpler cleaner approach available using other functions from the `raster` package.